# Calico Kubernetes Network Policy is denying all traffic and not working as expected

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, calico, kubectl

I am trying to implement some Calico based Kubernetes Network Policies.  I have already setup Calico in my cluster and all the Calico based pods are running fine.
In my cluster, There are two pods.
**1. An Nginx pod**
**2. An Apache pod**

My requirement is that I need to add a NetworkPolicy for controlling the network traffic in the Nginx pod. I want the egress trafic from the Nginx pod to the Apache pod to be blocked. However, I want to ping to 8.8.8.8 from the Nginx pod.

So in short, I want to block only the traffic to the Apache pod from the Nginx pod.
My YAML file is as follows:

**calico-deny-range-policy-yaml**

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-egress-external
  namespace: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app == 'nginx'
  types:
    - Egress
  egress:    
    - action: Deny
      protocol: TCP
      source:
        nets:
        - 192.168.163.0/25
      destination:
        nets:
        - 192.168.163.204/32
        notNets:
        - 8.8.8.8/32
```

But the problem is that the Nginx pod is getting a 'Deny All' effect. I am unable to ping any IPs from the Nginx pod. The whole traffic is getting blocked.

How can I customize the egress and ingress trafic according to my need? Any working examples for the above requirement is appreciated.

Comment: If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mention the destination pod in the selector label at destination as below :

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-egress-external
  namespace: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app == 'nginx'
  types:
    - Egress
  egress:    
    - action: Deny
      protocol: TCP
      source:
        nets:
        - 192.168.163.0/25
      destination:
        Selector:
          app == 'apache'
        nets:
        - 192.168.163.204/32
        notNets:
        - 8.8.8.8/32
```

Please refer to this doc for [calico network policy](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/reference/resources/networkpolicy#entityrule) and with [few examples](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/security/calico-network-policy).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This worked splendid!